# Mail does not override from email address in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am sending email using Gmail SMTP account, but I want show different sender email to the receiver. I am using below code to override the from email address.

```
Mail::send('emails_old.send_message', ['data' => $request->message], function ($message) use ($request, $toEmail, $cc, $bcc, $attacments)
  {
    $message->to($toEmail);
    $message->subject($request->subject);
    $message->from('no-reply@xyz', 'No reply');
    $message->replyTo(auth()->user()->email, auth()->user()->name);
  });
```

Above code working fine & also overrides sender name, but not email address.

can anybody tells what's wrong I am doing?

Thanks,
Kaleem

Comment: Gmail only permits you to use a `From` address that's in your Settings as a verified alias. You can't (and shouldn't) spoof an email address you don't control. If nothing else, it'll frequently be flagged as spam because of SPF records.

Comment: How can I be as verified alias?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370

Comment: But in my case there will not be same email address, I just want to override current login user email address & there will be thousands of user?
Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: As I stated, "you can't, and shouldn't" do that. That's what `replyTo` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Gmail only permits you to use a From address that's in your Settings as a verified alias. You can't (and shouldn't) spoof an email address you don't control. If nothing else, it'll frequently be flagged as spam because of SPF records. – ceejayoz

If you want to use a different email address where the mail is send from try using a mail server, or try using a maildriver such as mailgun.

I only use Gmail SMTP for development, after that I switch over to my mail server.

> I'd note that while other services may allow you to do this, it's still a horrible idea. SPF records will send a lot of email sent like this to spam. – ceejayoz

So if it's just for development or a school-project, you can use mailservices like mailgun or Gmail SMTP. Otherwise try to get a mail server to handle no-reply emails.

Comment: I'd note that while other services may *allow* you to do this, it's still a horrible idea. SPF records will send a lot of email sent like this to spam.

Comment: That's true, I will add that into the answer if you don't mind. @ceejayoz

Comment: Works for me! 